# Deployment Configuration - Execute only new and changed Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, deployment, properties

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 and TFS 2010.

I added a "SQL Server 2008 Database Project" to my solution for managing stored procedures etc. as you can see in the photo;

[image]

And I changed these sql scripts properties as "Build Action: Build" and "ANSI Nulls: Project Default". With that way, when I deploy the project all sql files will put in one sql file. And It will be ready to launched.

So here is my question; 
How can visual studio prepare/collect **only** all **new and changed** stored procedures in deployment? Because I can't run a sp after every development. I should take only new and changed ones. I think that kind of option is located in; VS2010 > Project Properties > Deploy > Deployment Configuration File | but I can't find it.

Please help me...

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Source Control Tool.
Please refer to this Link
[Getting sourcecontrol on stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513736/getting-sourcecontrol-on-stored-procedures)